# how to hide angularJs Code when page is refreshed?

Tags: angularjs

how to hide angularJs Code when page is refreshed ?

please see this :

[image]

how to hide `{{userInfo.UserName}}` when page is refreshed ?

this is Not user-friendly.

Comment: check ng-bind and ng-cloak directives

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `ng-cloak`:

```
<div id="template1" ng-cloak>{{ 'hello' }}</div>
<div id="template2" class="ng-cloak">{{ 'world' }}</div>
```

it hides given elements until your application is loaded. Note that documentation states that for best results, you should load `angular.js` in the head section, what ensures that functionality is accessible right after `head` has been processed.